# Migrating SQL Server to MySQL - Incorrect String Value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-migration

When migrating from SQL Server to MySQL, I'm having the error "Incorrect String Value" when the string has any Portuguese specific character (like in "Olá", which means hello).

The problem is that this occur in same tables, but not on others. I have a tableA which have this characters, but imports correctly, but another tableB gives me the error. Both tables have the same codepage.

I'm using the script generated my MySQL Migration Tool, which calls wbcopytables.exe.

Does anyone has any clue on what could be the problem?

Comment: consider `create table xxx (stuff) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`   and look at the per-column character set settings for overrides

Comment: What are the field types? Either the source *isn't* `nvarchar` or the target doesn't use UTF8. Such problems are always caused by using ASCII instead of Unicode and mixing codepages. The only real solution is to remove ambiguity and use Unicode throughout.

Comment: What are the collations and codepages of both source and target, database and table?